xsl for-each not triggered for array
I have xml like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:MT_JSON_in xmlns:ns0="http://testi.fi/sanoma">
<JSON>
<object>
<object name="invoiceList">
<array name="invoice">
<object>
<num name="id">1138073</num>

etc..
Last "object" can have multiple ocurrences.
and my xslt like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<!-- Mappauksen pääosio -->
<xsl:template match="/">
<ORDERS05>
  <xsl:for-each select="MT_JSON_in/JSON/object/object/array[@name='invoice']/object">
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <xsl:call-template name="addControlRecord"/>

etc...
But I can only produce the ORDERS05 element. For-each is not done.
Any ideas?

You need to take care of the namespace prefix as described in the linked post answer. Also you wouldn't need a xsl:for-each and xsl:call-template here - a simple template match would do just fine.

Hi Filburt, thanks for the tip. I got it working as instructed in the linked post.
